# titanium 1.7.5 sdk, iOS 5, on lion. kitchensink not building

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

The company I am working in is trying to develop our new mobile client side apps, for matters of "Develop once run an all", with the Appcelerator Titanium(SDk 1.7.5) iOS5 on a lion based Macs.

No one managed to work it out, so i'm a trying to figure this out during the weekend. I am getting the next build error (As a native developer for both IOS and Android I am used to work with the Xcode. From what i read in the site, i should build the app in the Titanium, not the XCODE??? the error when i am running form the Titanium, not the Xcode - the first unfamiliar item in my list....SHOULD I RUN IT IN THE TITANIUM OR THE XCODE FOR IOS?)

I can see that the build is starting and looking ok, if need all the log i will give it, but there are debug and info build lines and then i am getting this error and the build stops...
.
.
.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/[USER]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.5/iphone/builder.py", line 1222, in main
    execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=**LOG__ID**=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s %s" % (log_id,sdk_version,debugstr)],False)
    File "/Users/[USER]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.5/iphone/builder.py", line 1140, in execute_xcode
    output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
    File "/Users/[USER]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.7.5/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
    sys.exit(rc)
    SystemExit: 65

Other then that, I can the see that the engine in Python. Is it a problem with the python engine, the Titanium SDK or the the IOS SDK? When tried to run the "Hello world" app, we got more or less the same error.

Can any one help me with this issue? or send me to a good docs or tutorial to give me a direction?

Thank you,
Erez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my recommendation is to look in the `build/iphone/build` directory and open up the `build.log` to see what the real error is

Comment: It still doesn't give me any info...when i run on xcode the simulator opens but for some reason it doesn't happen with the titanium....